# Creation of especialized \Sexpr function version

Tags: r, sweave, r-exams

I'm using the `exams` package to generate some exams (engineering). My source files are in `Rnw` format so the underlying engine is Sweave.

In R side, I'm using `units` package (to check dimensionality correctness) and I've created a function (called `units2tex`) to convert a magnitude from units to LaTeX equivalent. So, when I calculate a variable, I have to create a copy for LaTeX:

```
<<>>=
R = set_units(1,ohm)
I = set_units(1,A)
V = R*I

R_tex = units2tex(R)
I_tex = units2tex(I)
#V_tex = units2tex(V)

@

For $R = \Sexpr{R_tex}$, the answer is \Sexpr{units2tex(V)}.
```

In both cases (to print `R` and `V`) I have to explicitly call `units2tex` function somewhere. It's is a lot of typing (more to type, more places to be wrong) because there are a lot of steps and intermediate temporal values.

**Is it possible to easily create versions of \Sexpr with automatic function calls?**

More concretely:

- Is is possible to create `\SexprT{V}` to function like `\Sexpr{units2tex(V)}`?
- Is is possible to create `\SexprT{V,digits=2}` (or similar) to function like `\Sexpr{units2tex(V,digits=2)}`?

In both cases without losing the use of original `\Sexpr`.

My current options and its cons:

- Explicitly call to `units2tex(...)` and duplicate variables (units version and LaTeX version). It is my current approach. A lot to typing, prone to forget conversions or generate conversions that they are not used latter.
- use very short function names: `\Sexpr{t(V)}`. Difficult to remember the meaning of each translation function. Pollution of the namespace. I still remember last time I use a `c` function (after `a` and `b` ones) and break original c function.
- Use some kind of preprocessor and made the changes. As I said before, all ecosystem is to work with exams package. This package executes Sweave in the background, I do not want to alter the pipeline of the files to generate the tests. I would write a `*.Rnw2` file and have to create a script in ¿sed? ¿R?, read files, modify values and generate the `*.Rnw` file and then call exams2pdf functions... There is problems if I forgot to update `Rnw` exams files. I'd use a Makefile to coordinate, but I have to switch between a terminal and Rstudio... This option is, maybe the best (after the creation of `\Sexpr` versions) but the solution obscures the pipeline and difficult quick questions generation to check them.

So, the best approach is: Is it possible to create variations of \Sexpr?

**Full example:** file: "question.Rnw"

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
library(units)

units2tex <- function(x) {
# this function is not important here. Simplified version the original version much complex
paste0(x,deparse_unit(x))
}

@


\begin{question}

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=

In <- set_units(1e-3,A)
Pn <- set_units(sample(c(2,1,0.5,0.25,0.125),1),W)

In_tex <- units2tex(In)
Pn_tex <- units2tex(Pn)

@

A resistor nah nah nah current $I_n=\Sexpr{In_tex}$ nah, nah, nah $P_n=\Sexpr{Pn_tex}$

What is V?

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
Vn <- set_units(Pn/In,V)
Vn_tex <- units2tex(Vn) 
@

\begin{answerlist}
  \item $V = \Sexpr{Vn_tex}$
  \item $V = \Sexpr{Pn_tex}$
  \item $V = \Sexpr{In_tex}$
\end{answerlist}    
\end{question}

\begin{solution}

To calculate $V$, we do $V= P_n/I_n = \frac{\Sexpr{Pn_tex}}{\Sexpr{In_tex}} = \Sexpr{Vn_tex}$
\begin{answerlist}
  \item Ok
  \item Bad
  \item Wrong
\end{answerlist}    
\end{solution}

\exname{question1}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{100}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

And to compile:

```
library(exams)
exams2html(c("question1.Rnw"), encoding="utf-8",template='plain8.html',mathjax = TRUE)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rnw exercises the content of `\Sexpr{}` is turned into character by explicitly calling `as.character()` on it. As this is a generic function you could easily define your own method, say,

```
as.character.units <- function(x, ...) units2tex(x, ...)
```

and then simply using `\Sexpr{V}` will automatically call your `units2tex()` function behind the scenes.

Note that the same does not work for Rmd exercises. So i you want to mix Rnw and Rmd exercises, then using a shortcut function name such as the following might be better:

```
u2t <- function(x, ...) units2tex(x, ...)
```

This would then need to be called as `\Sexpr{u2t(V)}` and `` `r u2t(V)` ``, respectively.

Comment: That solves the first question (kind of): The personalization of a type when using \Sexpr.

But the second one is unanswered: Definition of variants of Sexpr to express variants in data to show.

Comment: Thanks. To the best of my knowledge your ideal solution is not possible (customizing `\Sexpr`). So you can only combine the ideas above: different (sub)classes with different `as.character()` methods -or- different short functions.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the pollution namespace:

```
a <- list(t=function(x){units2tex(x)},d=function(x){units2tex(x,digits=2)})
```

and later `\Sexpr{a$t(V)}`

It's almost shorter than `\Sexpr{V_tex}` but I do not have to define `V_tex`.